# C# - DrawString draws text flipped

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, drawstring

I'm using a theme with a custom `TabControl` control.

The control draws text for each tab using the `DrawString` method like so:

```
using (SolidBrush B = new SolidBrush(FC))
{
    G.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Theme.GlobalFont(FontStyle.Regular, 10), B, new Point(TabRect.X + 50, TabRect.Y + 12));
}
```

After changing the text to Hebrew, and changing the control's `RightToLeftLayout` to true, the text is flipped like so:

[image: Example]

I tried to search online and found out that you can use `Transform` to modify the text, however I believe this is not the case since it should be a simple task. Here's the full class for the control:

```
class FirefoxMainTabControl : TabControl
{

    #region " Private "
    private Graphics G;
    private Rectangle TabRect;
    #endregion
    private Color FC = Color.Blue;

    #region " Control "

    public FirefoxMainTabControl()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        ItemSize = new Size(43, 152);
        Alignment = TabAlignment.Left;
        SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= TabPages.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                TabPages[i].BackColor = Color.White;
                TabPages[i].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(66, 79, 90);
                TabPages[i].Font = Theme.GlobalFont(FontStyle.Regular, 10);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        G = e.Graphics;
        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        G.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

        base.OnPaint(e);

        G.Clear(Color.FromArgb(66, 79, 90));


        for (int i = 0; i <= TabPages.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            TabRect = GetTabRect(i);


            if (SelectedIndex == i)
            {
                using (SolidBrush B = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(52, 63, 72)))
                {
                    G.FillRectangle(B, TabRect);
                }

                FC = Helpers.GreyColor(245);

                using (SolidBrush B = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 175, 54)))
                {
                    G.FillRectangle(B, new Rectangle(TabRect.Location.X - 3, TabRect.Location.Y + 1, 5, TabRect.Height - 2));
                }

            }
            else
            {
                FC = Helpers.GreyColor(192);

                using (SolidBrush B = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(66, 79, 90)))
                {
                    G.FillRectangle(B, TabRect);
                }

            }

            using (SolidBrush B = new SolidBrush(FC))
            {
                G.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Theme.GlobalFont(FontStyle.Regular, 10), B, new Point(TabRect.X + 50, TabRect.Y + 12));
            }

            if ((ImageList != null))
            {
                if (!(TabPages[i].ImageIndex < 0))
                {
                    G.DrawImage(ImageList.Images[TabPages[i].ImageIndex], new Rectangle(TabRect.X + 19, TabRect.Y + ((TabRect.Height / 2) - 10), 18, 18));
                }
            }

        }

    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(-1,1) would be the workaraound, but I have to agree it is a bit hackish..

Comment: Hmya, you are voiding the warranty by not using the TabControl.DrawMode property.  The Graphics instance you get was setup to achieve the RightToLeft rendering you asked for.  Which affects *everything* you draw, also the text.  You'll have to undo this again with G.ScaleTransform(-1, 1) and G.TranslateTransform().

Comment: @TaW After using that the top line is gone (text) and the second line is still flipped.

Comment: It is gone because you ddn't pull/translate it back into view. Also : You need to scale/translate before each drawstring and ResetTransform after. Or follow Hans' advice of following the rules and paint in the DrawItem event..

Comment: @HansPassant What parameters do I use for the scaling?

Comment: The scaling is simple, -1, 1.  Figuring out the TranslateTransform() arguments is your job.